# How to select all the sub_category records with its main_category_name and parent_id in a single query in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

My category table is looking like the following:

```
------------------------------------
id  |   name         | parent_id   |
------------------------------------
1   |  Vehicles      |   0         |
2   |  Car Insurance |   1         |
3   |  Van Insurance |   1         |
4   |  PhoneRecharge |   0         |
5   |  prepaid       |   4         |
6   |  postpaid      |   4         |
```

The output should look like the following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------
id  | parent_id | main_category_name | sub_category_name|
---------------------------------------------------------
2   |  1        |   Vehicles         | Car Insurance    |
3   |  1        |   Vehicles         | Van Insurance    |
5   |  4        |   PhoneRecharge    | prepaid          |
6   |  4        |   PhoneRecharge    | postpaid         |
```

To get the above record, I need to minimize my database interaction. So I need to achieve this above data in a single query.

Comment: Is it just me, or don't the ID's match up with one and each other? Show us the query's you execute in order to fetch the desired data.

Comment: SELECT catg.`id`,cat.`id`, cat.`name` as `main_cat_name`, catg.`name` as `sub_catagory_name`
FROM
    `catagory` cat, `catagory` catg
WHERE cat.`id` = catg.`parent_id`

use this query stated below @Xorifelse

Answer (score 3):

Here you go: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b1a7a/14

SQL: 
`SELECT * FROM category t1 INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM category WHERE parent_id != 0) t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent_id`

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
SELECT
  c.id AS cat_id,
      parent.id AS parent_id,
  parent.name AS main_category_name,
  c.name AS sub_category_name
FROM
  category c JOIN category parent ON c.parent_id = parent.id
```